# Scala - How to convert a Date String to a timestamp in a Spark SQL query?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, datetime, apache-spark-sql

I have a `formattedDataInputDateTime` String that I want to insert into a table as a Timestamp type as a second field.

```
// Returns 2019-10-30T13:00Z
val localDateTimeZoned = OffsetDateTime.of(java.time.LocalDate.parse(currentDate), java.time.LocalTime.now, ZoneOffset.UTC).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS)

// Returns 2019-10-30T13:00:00.000+0000
val formattedDataInputDateTime: String = localDateTimeZoned.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx")).toString
```

So I wrote the following query but can't figure out how to insert the `formattedDataInputDateTime` as a timestamp here?

```
spark.sql(
  s"""INSERT INTO main.basic_metrics
     |VALUES ('metric_name', ???,
     |'metric_type', current_timestamp, false)""".stripMargin)
```

I've tried to test this approach but it resulted in the following error:

```
val ts = cast(unix_timestamp("$formattedDataInputDateTime", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx") as timestamp)

type mismatch;
 found   : String("$formattedDataInputDateTime")
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

Comment: `"$formattedDataInputDateTime"` is incorrect. You need `$"formattedDataInputDateTime"`.  The $ and first " are reversed.  (I do this all the time).  It may not solve everything for you, but it needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
val ts = cast(unix_timestamp("$formattedDataInputDateTime", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx") as timestamp)

type mismatch;
 found   : String("$formattedDataInputDateTime")
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

This basically means the $ is inside the quoted string. It should be outside like `$"formattedDataInputDateTime"`

Comment: I've changed it to `$"formattedDataInputDateTime"` but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you update your question with a reproducible code snippet so that we can see what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `String` instead of `Column`, you can wrap it using `lit`:

`cast(unix_timestamp(lit(formattedDataInputDateTime), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx")`

However you can get current date and format it using spark functions `current_date` and `date_format`.

Comment: `formattedDataInputDateTime` is not a column name, it's a String `2019-10-30T13:00:00.000+0000` that I need to pass as a timestamp